# Unable to find SUBCLIPSE in this eclipse provided by adt bundle

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded adt bundle for android . This bundle contains an inbuilt eclipse. I am not finding the way that how can i add SUBCLIPSE in this eclipse provided by adt bundle as it does not contain the option named eclipse marketplace. 
how can i do this,please guide me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try following
 go to help ->  Install new software then  provide the url of subclipse http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x it gives pacage names to be install click on next then install subclipse will get installed on your eclipse.